# Angular 2 filter in JSON response

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have problem filtering data from JSON response. I am using Google Geocoding API and get response where i want to retrtive only city name. The city name is stored in JSON response in one of the array, where `types= "locality", "political"`

[image: JSON response]

How to retrive city name where `types=["locality", "political"]`?

Here is my code:

**geocoding.service.ts**

```
 getLocation(lat: number, lon: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + lat + ',' + lon + '&key' + this.apiKey)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response) => Promise.resolve(response.json()));
  }
```

**geocoding.ts**

```
export class Geocoding {
    results: {
        address_components: {
            long_name: string;
            short_name: string;
        }
        formatted_address: string;
        types: {
            array: string;
            length: number;
        }
    }
    status: string;
}
```

**weather.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { GeocodingService } from '../data/google/geocoding/geocoding.service';
import { Geocoding } from '../data/google/geocoding/geocoding';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.scss']
})

  location: Geocoding[];
  datasource: Geocoding[];
  sortedList: Geocoding[];

 ngOnInit() {
    this.findLocation2(52.406374, 16.9251681);
  }

 findLocation2(latitude: number, longtitude: number) {
    this.GeoService.getLocation(latitude, longtitude).then(data => {
      this.datasource = data;
      this.location = this.datasource;
      this.sortedList = this.location.filter(
        loc => loc.results.types.array === 'locality,political');
    });
```

When i run i get error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.location.filter is not a function

Comment: There are quite a few questions dealing with this problem. You only get plain JSON from the service, not a JS object with functions. You need to have a constructor that takes the JSON and creates a viable object.

Comment: i found the solution, please find below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Both @Ramesh Rajendran and @Sebastian pointed me in the right directions:

```
 findLocation(latitude: number, longtitude: number) {
    return this.GeoService.getData(latitude, longtitude).subscribe(g => {
      this.geo = g;
      this.GEOARRAY = g.results;
      if (isArray(this.GEOARRAY)) {
        this.location = this.GEOARRAY.filter(x => x.types[0] === "locality" && x.types[1] === "political");
      }
    });
  }
```

I created `GEOARRAY` and pointed to `g.results` (which was array). Then i filtered what i wanted :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this.location` is should be an array. So you need to check if `this.location` is an array before you are doing `filter`.

```
findLocation2(latitude: number, longtitude: number) {
    this.GeoService.getLocation(latitude, longtitude).then(data => {
      this.datasource = data;
      this.location = this.datasource;
      if(Array.isArray(this.location)){
      this.sortedList = this.location.filter(
        loc => loc.results.types.array === 'locality,political');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Error is fixed, but when i want to `console.log(this.sortedList);` it is `undefined`.

Comment: Because `this.location` is not an array. So you should check `getLocation` is returns array or not.

Comment: i found the solution, please find below